# Trying to speed up production build using Gradle with Azure Devops

Tags: azure

## https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android

pool:

`vmImage: 'macos-latest`

steps:

```
 -task: Bash@3
 - displayName: Check for skippable builds
   inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
       if  [ -z $(apk_flavor_prod) ]
       then
             echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skip_prod]true"
       else
             echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skip_prod]false"
       fi
       if  [ -z $(apk_flavor_uat) ]
       then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skip_uat]true"
      else
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skip_uat]false"
      fi
      if  [ -z $(apk_flavor_staging) ]
      then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skip_staging]true"
      else
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skip_staging]false"
      fi
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'Maven Authenticate'
  inputs:
    artifactsFeeds: HorizonAndroidSDK
- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: Build production
  condition: and(in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Failed'), eq(variables['skip_prod'], false))
  inputs:
 
    workingDirectory: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/OpenOrderBook_Android'
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/OpenOrderBook_Android/gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    tasks: 'assemble$(apk_flavor_prod)'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
 
- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: Build UAT
  condition: and(in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Failed'), eq(variables['skip_uat'], false))
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/OpenOrderBook_Android'
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/OpenOrderBook_Android/gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    tasks: 'assemble$(apk_flavor_uat)'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
 
- task: Gradle@2
  displayName: Build staging
  condition: and(in(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Failed'), eq(variables['skip_staging'], false))
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/OpenOrderBook_Android'
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/OpenOrderBook_Android/gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    tasks: 'assemble$(apk_flavor_staging)'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
 
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: Copy files to artifacts directory
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    contents: '**/*.apk'
    targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  displayName: Publish Artifacts
```

'So when I deploy this in my azure devops using gradle for my android build, it runs very slow esp in the production build which can take up to half an hour and also in 'Build UAT' and 'Build staging'. Now I know there is a gradle 3 but can anyone look at my code and make any recommendations as to how I can deploy this faster as takes forever etc. `

Comment: Hey buddy, wrong StackExchange. This is for database-centric questions. You're probably looking for [StackOverflow](https://StackOverflow.com).